# SQL query not working as expected (from a beginners point of view)

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to get all the rows with the specific `session_id` and also that do not have '3223' for the `group_with` column. So I have this SQL statement :

```
SELECT * FROM pr_cart WHERE session_id=203130570714 AND group_with != 3223
```

Which to me it looks fine, but for some reason it does not return anything.

In my table I have entries that should not meet the criteria. i.e.

`session_id=203130570714 | group_with=3225` which **should be** returned.
`session_id=203130570714 | group_with=NULL` which **should be** returned.
`session_id=203130570714 | group_with=3223` which **should *not*** be returned.

I tried:

1. `<>` instead of `!=`
2. `NOT (group_with=3223)`
3. `group_with NOT LIKE '3223'`

How can I get all the rows with the specified `session_id` and that also have a different number than `3223` for the `group_with`

**edit** session_id is varchar and group_with is int

Comment: What's the datatypes of session_id and group_with?

Comment: you refer to 3223 in clause, but data shows 3225 or is that just a type-o

Comment: @DRapp I just typed one data set, there is also one with 3223 that should not be returned, you are right I will clarify :D

Comment: @daZza `session_id` is `varchar` and `group_with` is `int`

Comment: Quote the `session_id` value. That should do the trick

Comment: Interesting, can you provide sqlfiddle if it hasn't been resolved yet?

Comment: @JA It has, SO wouldn't let me choose answer as correct for 5 mins! :P

Comment: @alexandros Glad it is solved, I've never got in similar situation. Learned something new regarding != with NULL. Great clarifications btw.

Comment: This is a refreshingly good question. The handling of NULL values in SQL is an important one and not intuitive for a beginner.

Comment: @JA cheers, yes I guess it shows the importance of details :P

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`NULL` is a special value which you must take special care of:

```
SELECT * FROM pr_cart WHERE session_id="203130570714" AND
  (group_with != 3223 OR group_with IS NULL)
```

### General recommendation

Basically all operations, which involve `NULL` as one operand, yield `NULL` as result.

```
SELECT NULL + 5; # NULL
SELECT NULL * 5; # NULL
SELECT NULL NOT IN (234); # NULL
SELECT 5 IN (NULL); # NULL
```

`NULL` will never be interpreted neither as `true` nor as `false` and is therefore literally useless for deciding if a row should be contained in the result set or not.

Whenever one has a column definition, which allows `NULL` values, one must take special care of these values.

Comment: Thats the cool part in being a begginner at something, you learn something everyday :D cheers!

Comment: @JA No, it does not. `NULL NOT INT (3223)` returns `NULL` which is not `true`.

Answer (score -1):

If SQL Server than try the below:-

Let try the below script if the datatype of the session_id and group_with is int means,

```
SELECT * FROM pr_cart WHERE session_id in(203130570714) AND group_with not in(3223)
```

If datatype id varchar try the below script,

```
SELECT * FROM pr_cart WHERE session_id in('203130570714') AND group_with not in('3223')
```

you will get your output.

Comment: [This also does not return the row with `NULL` value.](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/d9009/2)

Comment: By the way: This question is clearly about MySQL, not Microsoft SQL Server.

Comment: Oh sorry i posted it for MS Sql Server

Comment: Your answer would be wrong for MS SQL server too, see the linked sqlfiddle.